# Store a complex hash in Apache::Sessions:MySQL session

Tags: mysql, json, apache, perl, session

So, I'm trying to store a decoded JSON object into a tied apache session. This is my code:

```
    $url="https://apilink";

    $content = get($url);
    die "Can't Get $url" if (! defined $content);

    $jsonOb = decode_json($content);
    %aprecords = %$jsonOb;

    #Push the jsonOb in the session
    $session{apirecords} = \%aprecords ;
```

`$session{apirecords}` does not store the `%aprecords` reference. Although, when I substitute the statement to `$session{apirecords} = \%jsonOb ;` , it stores `apirecords` in the sessions table but the reference to %jsonOb has no values in it.

PS:
I have tried the following and none of them seem to work:
1) `$session{apirecords} = \%$jsonOb ;`
2) `$session{apirecords} = { %aprecords } ;`

JSON object is perfectly well structured.

Code for tying a session:

```
  tie %session, "Apache::Session::MySQL", $sessionID, 
   {
    Handle => $dbObject,
    LockHandle => $dbObject,
    TableName => 'sessions',
    };

  #If a session ID doesn't exist, create a new session and get new session ID
  if (!defined ($sessionID)){
     $sessionID = $session{_session_id};
     $session{count}=0;
}
```

A helping hand would be much much appreciated!

JSON Sample: https://jsonblob.com/feed3bba-f1cd-11e8-9450-2904e8ecf943

Comment: Let's try and narrow down the issue. If you store a simple scalar value instead of a json data structure, do you meet the same issue or you are able to then retrieve the data ?

Comment: @GMB yes, if I say `$session{apirecords} = "hello";` it does store "hello" as an entry. When I change it to  `$session{apirecords} = "$content";` it doesn't store the encoded json held by $content

Comment: Allright, then what happens if you store a simple hash reference, like $session{api_records} = { hello => "world" }; Are you able to recover it afterwards ? Also, can you show us what the JSON data looks like before you store it, using Data::Dumper for example ?

Comment: Okay so, I tried `$session{apirecords} = { hello => "world" };` and then I tried to retrieve it using `%helloOb = %{$session{apirecords}}; print $helloOb{hello};` The result was: `world`  , which means it worked! The JSON looks like: https://jsonblob.com/feed3bba-f1cd-11e8-9450-2904e8ecf943

Comment: OK thanks.That's quite a big JSON object. What is the type and size of the database field where you try to store it ? Maybe you JSON just can't fit in the storage

Comment: You know what? you might be absolutely right there. I'm provided with a MariaDB  instance, the type of the field is blob! I'm not 100% sure of the size. Is there another way I can store a JSON object this big for session management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by GMB. The blob size(64 KB) wasn't big enough for the JSON object. 
The solution is to change `blob` datatype to `mediumblob` .